# Why does my button with an ICommand binding not immediately appear disabled when clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, icommand, canexecute

I have a simple WPF program with an `ICommand`.  I am finding that the button doesn't enable/disable as I would expect.  I can illustrate this best with a contrived code example:

```
class Reload : ICommand
{
    private readonly BackgroundWorker _bworker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public Reload()
    {
        this._isExecuting = false;

        this._bworker.DoWork += this._bworker_DoWork;
        this._bworker.RunWorkerCompleted += this._bworker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    private void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if (this.CanExecuteChanged != null)
            this.CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private bool _isExecuting;
    private void SetIsExecuting(bool isExecuting)
    {
        this._isExecuting = isExecuting;
        this.OnCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return !this._isExecuting;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        //this does not update the GUI immediately
        this.SetIsExecuting(true);

        //This line doesn't fix my problem
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();

        //during this wait, button appears "clicked"
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)); //simulate first calculation

        this._bworker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void _bworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //during this wait, button appears disabled
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)); //simulate second calculation
    }

    private void _bworker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //this updates immediately
        this.SetIsExecuting(false);
    }
}
```

In the `Execute(object)` method, I trigger the `CanExecuteChanged` event in a way that will cause `CanExecute(object)` to return false.  After that call, I expect the button to become disabled immediately, but it doesn't become disabled until some point between the call to `RunWorkerAsync()` and the second simulated calculation.

In the background worker's `RunWorkerCompleted(...)` event handler, I again trigger the `CanExecuteChanged` event, but this time in a way that will cause `CanExecuteChanged(object)` to return true.  After this call, the button immediately becomes enabled.

Why does the button not immediately appear as disabled when I trigger the `CanExecuteChanged` event?

*Note #1: that the first simulated calculation represents code that I have that should run on the main GUI thread.  If I remove this call, the button acts as I would expect.*

*Note #2: I've read about using `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` to force the code to call the `CanExecute(object)` method.  I've shown in my comments that this isn't working for me.  Considering that I call `OnCanExecuteChanged(...)`, I think that that suggestion is redundant anyway.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The *right* solution is the one you've already found, move the first long-running operation off of the UI thread.**

However, if you can't do that, the problem is that you aren't giving the UI a chance to run its binding and update the state. It probably updates as soon as the background worker starts (because control is returned from your function).

You could take advantage of [`async/await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) and [Task.Delay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx) to give up some time for the UI to update:

```
public async void Execute(object parameter)
{
    //this does not update the GUI immediately
    this.SetIsExecuting(true);

    //Delays this function executing, gives the UI a chance to pick up the changes
    await Task.Delay(500);

    //during this wait, button appears "clicked"
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)); //simulate first calculation

    this._bworker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Async/Await allows you to execute an operation asynchronously, and wait for it to finish, while allowing the current thread to continue executing (outside of the current method call). Its not super easy to explain all the technical details, see the link for more info.

I would wait at least 20ms, and probably 50ms. Obviously delaying like this isn't the *cleanest* solution, but without removing the `Sleep` (or moving the code it represents off the UI thread) your options are pretty limited.

Comment: that worked.  Two questions: (1) Do you know the underlying mechanism that makes this work?  I'm not familiar with async/await and I'd rather not put in delays simply to make code work.  And (2), do you know the minimum delay I can use in the Task.Delay call?  One msec is apparently too small.

Comment: It would be even better to move the first calculation off the UI thread, if at all possible.

Comment: @StephenCleary Totally agreed, which I tried to point out in my last paragraph, but I will highlight it better.

Comment: @StephenCleary, in my actual code, that first calculation is intertwined with UI updates via many calls to OnPropertyChanged. If I could move that code into the BackgroundWorker without big changes, I would.